# Can not get "setPropertyId" in "Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest"

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-4

I have a GA4 account and propertyId created, I have created the service account and got the JSON file also.

I am implementing a code in which I want to get the Google Analytics data for my PHP application.

I have added the composer and also the package:

```
"google/apiclient": "^2.14",
```

This is the code i am trying to get the data.

```
// Create a Google Analytics service object.
$analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting(
    [
        'credentials' => file_get_contents('client_secrets.json'),
    ]
);

// Create a request object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();

// Set the property ID.
$request->setPropertyId('YOUR_PROPERTY_ID');

// Set the dimensions and metrics that you want to get.
$request->setDimensions(['ga:pagePath', 'ga:visits']);
$request->setMetrics(['ga:users', 'ga:bounceRate']);

// Call the Google Analytics API.
$response = $analytics->reports()->batchGet($request);

// Get the results.
foreach ($response->getReports() as $report) {
    foreach ($report->getData() as $row) {
        // Print the results.
        echo $row->getDimensions()[0] . ': ' . $row->getMetrics()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

But in this line:

```
$request->setPropertyId('YOUR_PROPERTY_ID');
```

I get the **error**

```
Error
Call to undefined method Google\Service\AnalyticsReporting\ReportRequest::setPropertyId()
```

I am doing this first time, so also please help me if I am not on the correct path.

Comment: How do you understand the error message? Why did you choose to call the method named _setPropertyId_? Please provide the reference (manual) you're working with for that method.

Comment: Hello @hakre 
sorry sir but i have reach here using google search, i get that the package i install that does not have the method i am calling, 
if you can guide me how can i get the GA4 analytics data , that will be helpfull sir

Comment: Have you tried searching the documentation for the functionality you're looking for? It should reveal it if it exists. Otherwise you have to sit and wait.

Comment: Just now but not sure I get that i am searching in "Reporting API V4" in google but i have GA4 property so i needed to check this "Data API V1 (Beta)" that has a property id.

Comment: You go to packagist for that package -> https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient -> then you scroll down and find diverse documentation references, you're probably looking for _Developer Documentation_, but not sure and see for yourself. You find more information on that page in any case, and that's normally the place to start if you don't have any other. Find a listing of all libs here: https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference